# Getting a Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError when using custom AttributeConverter for Neo4j Spring Boot JPA

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm, spring-data-neo4j-5

I have a Kotlin (v1.1.4) Spring Boot (v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) application running with Spring Data Neo4j (v5.0.0RC2), Neo4j (v3.2.1), and Neo4j OGM (v3.0.0).

I am receiving the following error when attempting to use a custom JPA `@Query` with a field that has a custom `AttributeConverter`.

Stack Trace:

```
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError; Description: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError; Description: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SessionFactoryUtils.convertOgmAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:153)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.translateExceptionIfPossible(SessionBeanDefinitionRegistrarPostProcessor.java:71)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:216)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.createBelongsToRelationship(Unknown Source)
        at com.yellowbird.mbi.service.StoreServiceImpl.updateVendorStoreRelationship(StoreServiceImpl.kt:26)
        at com.yellowbird.mbi.service.StoreServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e7299ffb.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AbstractTraceInterceptor.invoke(AbstractTraceInterceptor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at com.yellowbird.mbi.service.StoreServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3e3291f9.updateVendorStoreRelationship(<generated>)
        at com.yellowbird.mbi.service.StoreServiceIT.givenVendorId13_getVendorByVendorId_returnsVendorWithId13(StoreServiceIT.kt:28)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
        at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError; Description: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
        at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.executeRequest(EmbeddedRequest.java:176)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.execute(EmbeddedRequest.java:78)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.executeAndMap(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:117)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:86)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:391)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:131)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.query(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.execute(GraphQueryExecution.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.doExecute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:77)
        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:51)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:565)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:549)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        ... 47 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException.asUserException(QueryExecutionKernelException.java:35)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.executeQuery(ClassicCoreSPI.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:430)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.execute(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:413)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.executeRequest(EmbeddedRequest.java:172)
        ... 69 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ExecutionEngine.java:65)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.executeQuery(ClassicCoreSPI.java:78)
        ... 72 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.CypherTypeException: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.exceptionHandler$.cypherTypeException(exceptionHandler.scala:60)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.exceptionHandler$.cypherTypeException(exceptionHandler.scala:27)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.v3_2.CypherTypeException.mapToPublic(CypherException.scala:48)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.exceptionHandler$runSafely$.apply(exceptionHandler.scala:95)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(Compatibility.scala:100)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(PreparedPlanExecution.scala:26)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:107)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ExecutionEngine.java:61)
        ... 73 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.v3_2.CypherTypeException: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.helpers.CastSupport$.getConverter(CastSupport.scala:106)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.mutation.makeValueNeoSafe$.transformTraversableToArray(makeValueNeoSafe.scala:54)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.mutation.makeValueNeoSafe$.apply(makeValueNeoSafe.scala:29)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v3_2$pipes$BaseRelationshipPipe$$setProperty(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:77)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe$$anonfun$setProperties$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:63)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe$$anonfun$setProperties$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3.foreach(Map.scala:161)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe$$anonfun$setProperties$1.apply(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:62)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe$$anonfun$setProperties$1.apply(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:56)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe.setProperties(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:56)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v3_2$pipes$BaseRelationshipPipe$$createRelationship(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:45)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:38)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.BaseRelationshipPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(CreateRelationshipPipe.scala:38)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.EagerAggregationPipe.internalCreateResults(EagerAggregationPipe.scala:89)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:82)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:96)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:74)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:103)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:86)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anon$1.run(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:55)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Compatibility.scala:102)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Compatibility.scala:100)
        at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.exceptionHandler$runSafely$.apply(exceptionHandler.scala:90)
        ... 77 more
```

Here is my converter:

```
class ZonedDateTimeStringConverter : AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, String> {

    companion object {
        private val DATE_TIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
    }

    override fun toGraphProperty(value: ZonedDateTime?): String? = when (value) {
        null -> null
        else -> DATE_TIME_FORMAT.format(value)
    }

    override fun toEntityAttribute(value: String?): ZonedDateTime? = when (value) {
        null -> null
        else -> ZonedDateTime.parse(value, DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
    }
}
```

I have a relationship entity here:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "PART_OF")
data class PartOf(

    /*
     * @GraphId, @StartNode, @EndNode defined here)
     */

    @Convert(ZonedDateTimeStringConverter::class)
    var sinceDate: ZonedDateTime? = null

)
```

My JPA query is as follows:

```
@Query("MATCH (s:EntityOne {identifier: {entityOneIdentifier}})" +
        " MATCH (v:EntityTwo {identifier: {entitiyTwoIdentifier}})" +
        " CREATE (v)-[:PART_OF {createDate: {createDate}, sinceDate: {sinceDate}, active: {active}}]->(s) " +
        " RETURN count(s) > 0")
fun createPartOfRelationship(@Param("entityOneIdentifier") entityOneId: Long,
                                @Param("entityTwoIdentifier") entityTwoId: Long,
                                @Param("createDate") createDate: ZonedDateTime,
                                @Param("sinceDate") sinceDate: ZonedDateTime,
                                @Param("active") active: Boolean): Boolean
```

Looking at the Spring Data for Neo4j reference online, it looks like I have everything in place. The OGM properly sees the converter (I was able to debug and see that the static `companion object` inside of the class was being created / hit.

So, I assumed Spring Data might need to know about the converter. So, per the documentation, I added a `ConversionService` into my spring configuration.

```
@Bean
fun conversionService(@Autowired sessionFactory: SessionFactory): ConversionService =
    MetaDataDrivenConversionService(sessionFactory.metaData())
```

This does work using `java.util.Date` like the Spring Data Neo4j documentation says it should (its auto configured) stated here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_conversion

Does anyone have any suggestions to try or as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to have parameters like this

```
@Param("createDate") createDate: ZonedDateTime
```

in `@Query` annotated repository methods.

The target type in this case is `String`, but could be `Integer`, `Double` etc.. and the query would be the same - SDN doesn't know the type you need to convert to, so you need to do the conversion to correct type  yourselves (for the query parameters).